# Stringify the object getting "\"

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I am trying to stringify the object which  has another stringify object. I am getting `\`added to inside object

```
a   = {}
str = {'a': 'test'}
a.str = JSON.stringify(str);

console.log("=="+  (a));
console.log("strin " + JSON.stringify(a) ) // {"str":"{\"a\":\"test\"}"}


expected:  {"str":"{"a":"test"}"}
```

Comment: The extra slashes are just escaped characters, you can read more about it in the [Escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) section on this page

Answer (score 2):

What you expect would not be valid JSON.

Quotes are used to *delimit* strings in a JSON text.

With your expected result a JSON parser would see `"{"` and think that was the whole string and then `a` would be an error.

The escape sequence `\"` is how you say "This is a quote that is a part of a string" instead of "This is a quote that ends the string".

The output is fine. There is nothing wrong.

---

That said, nesting JSON is generally a bad idea. It is more complicated to parse and harder to read.

In general you should be creating the complete data structure and then stringifying that.

```js
const a = {};
const str = {
  'a': 'test'
};
a.str = str;
const json = JSON.stringify(a, null, 2);
console.log(`result: ${json}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an error

`str = {'a': 'test}`

It should be

`str = {'a': 'test'}`

The reason you are getting '' is simply because they are escaping double strings

This is illegal:

`"{"str":"{"a":"test"}"}"`

This is legal:

`"{\"str\":\"{\"a\":\"test\"}\"}"`

Comment: That looks like an error in the creation of the test case. It isn't the problem being asked about and cannot cause the problem described.